# How can I randomly select groups in a proportionate way?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to random select rows proportionate to the number of unique values in column "ID" grouping by column "Team". Further, I would like to only retrieve 9 total rows. I have:

```
|  ID   |  Team |  Color       |
| ----- | ----- | ------------ |
|  1    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  2    |  B    |  Red         |
|  2    |  B    |  Green       |
|  3    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  6    |  C    |  Red         |
|  1    |  B    |  Yellow      |
|  2    |  B    |  Green       |
|  9    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  6    |  C    |  Red         |
|  1    |  B    |  Yellow      |
|  9    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  1    |  A    |  Purple      |
```

Only the proportions are looking at unique values. The rows pulled do not necessarily need to be unique in anyway. Using the above table the proportions would be:

```
|  Team  | Unique IDs |  Proportion |  Number selected |
| ------ | ---------- | ----------- | ---------------- |
|  A     |    3       |  0.500      |       4          |
|  B     |    2       |  0.333      |       3          |
|  C     |    1       |  0.167      |       1          |
```

So since I want 8 total rows selected proportionately, I should end up with something like the following:

```
|  ID   |  Team |  Color       |
| ----- | ----- | ------------ |
|  1    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  3    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  9    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  1    |  A    |  Purple      |
|  2    |  B    |  Green       |
|  2    |  B    |  Red         |
|  1    |  B    |  Yellow      |
|  6    |  C    |  Red         |
```

I have a working method which basically does this but I sometimes end up with 0 selected for a group. I would like for all those with less than 0.5% to round up to one so that it can be selected. I would also like to not exceed the n_total. I currently have the following code

```py
n_total = 8
unique_counts = CaseLoad.groupby("Team")["ID"].agg("nunique")
nums_selected = pd.Series.round((unique_counts / unique_counts.sum() * n_total)).astype(
    int
)

Selection = main.groupby("Team", group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.sample(n=nums_selected[x.name], random_state=42, replace=False)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the datafram you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 1, 2, 9, 6, 1, 9, 1],
        "Team": ["A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "A",],
        "Color": ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Red", "Yellow", "Blue", "Purple"]
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Setup
N_TOTAL = 8

if N_TOTAL < df["Team"].nunique():
    raise ValueError(
        f"Number of rows ({N_TOTAL}) can not be less than "
        + f"number of unique teams ({df['Team'].nunique()})."
    )
```

```py
# Compute proportions 
proportions = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        N_TOTAL
        * df.groupby(["Team"]).nunique()["ID"]
        / df.groupby(["Team"]).nunique()["ID"].sum()
    )
    .round()
    .astype(int)
    .rename(columns={"ID": "Num"})
)

# Deal with low proportions to get at least one row
proportions["Num"] = proportions.apply(
    lambda x: 1 if x["Num"] == 0 else x["Num"], axis=1
)
proportions["Num"] = proportions.apply(
    lambda x: x["Num"]
    if x["Num"] == 1
    else x["Num"] - (proportions["Num"].sum() - N_TOTAL),
    axis=1,
)
proportions = proportions.reset_index()

# Get sample
sample = (
    df.groupby("Team", group_keys=False)
    .apply(
        lambda x: x.sample(
            n=proportions.loc[
                proportions["Team"] == x.name, "Num"
            ].values[0],
            replace=False,
        )
    )
    .sort_values(by=["Team", "ID"])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Then:

```py
print(sample)
# Output
   ID Team   Color
0   1    A  Purple
1   1    A    Blue
2   3    A    Blue
3   9    A    Blue
4   1    B  Yellow
5   2    B   Green
6   2    B     Red
7   6    C     Red
```